# Pass Image path from JSON in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a image in image folder, i want to pass the path to the image tag through a json file. how to achieve this?

My Json file (serviceDetails):

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "ServiceImage": "../assets/images/officeCleaning.jpg",
}]
```

Image tag in My Component:

```
<img src={require({serviceDetails.ServiceImage})} />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I hope you have proper `json-loader` setup in your webpack or any build tool config file. Then:

Either change your json to this:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "ServiceImage": "../assets/images/officeCleaning.jpg"
}
```

and use it like below:

```
import serviceDetails from './serviceDetails.json';

<img src={require(serviceDetails.ServiceImage)} />
```

But if its an array then use below:

```
<img src={require(serviceDetails[0].ServiceImage)} />
```

Comment: This can work if the JSON is a static resource. Not possible if the JSON is a dynamic resource read at runtime.

Comment: I Tried it, it shows Error: Cannot find module 'undefined'

Comment: Use told she has a static json file serviceDetails.json

Comment: @NandhiniKajol put the proper path of json file in import statement

Comment: @ManishJangir i imported right, because i have other content in json file that i use to display in my component. only this image path problem is there now